# How to use variable url and varible destination-output-file in wget

Tags: ruby, wget

I'm trying to execute following `ruby` script:

```
file_name = "/Users/x/y/z.zip"
url = "http://something.com/z.zip"
system('wget #{url} -O #{file_name}')
```

but I got an error:

```
Error:
wget: missing URL
Usage: wget [OPTION]... [URL]...
Try `wget --help' for more options.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Single vs. double quotes: String interpolation (i.e. `"#{x}"`) only happens in the latter one. If you substitute `puts` for `system` in your script:

```
file_name = "/Users/x/y/z.zip"
url = "http://something.com/z.zip"
puts 'wget #{url} -O #{file_name}'
puts "wget #{url} -O #{file_name}"
```

you will get this output:

```
wget #{url} -O #{file_name}
wget http://something.com/z.zip -O /Users/x/y/z.zip
```